# Windows Media Center showing Jerky Video on PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I had to repave my Windows 7 x64 box last week due to a hard drive crash, and for a while everything was running perfectly but now all videos in Windows Media Center are jerky (the sound is fine, they just seem to skip a ton of frames all the time).  This is on the local machine, but the same thing happens when I try to stream to my Xbox.  The videos all show fine in VLC and Windows Media Player (however exhibit the same problem in Quicktime).  I guess I must have installed something recently (in the process of getting all the apps I usually have running on my PC) that caused this but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  I have updated to the latest video driver (and then rolled back to the standard Windows 7 driver), I have rolled back all the other drivers that I have installed (I believe).  I have uninstalled all the codec packs (I also run TVersity, so I have the TVersity codec pack installed), and I uninstalled TVersity.  Nothing seems to help.  I have uninstalled windows media center, and reinstalled it from the Programs and Features.  I have basically ran out of things to try to fix this, and am almost thinking about reinstalling Windows again.  Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Specs on the PC (which I figured was unimportant since everything used to work perfectly):

Intel Core 2 CPU 6600 @ 2.4 Ghz
Nvidia GTS 8800
Built in realtek-audio soundcard
4GB Ram

Codecs which are failing:
All that I have tried, but at least Xvid, Mpgv (mpeg2 video from a camera), and Wmv (only kinds that I have ready access to).

Comment: What are the specs of your PC? What codec are these videos?

Answer (score 0):

If it were just your 360 that was stuttering, I'd say it was network traffic: this happens to me if I'm downloading torrents or anything else that consumes a lot of bandwidth; the whole network will get bogged down and my videos will stutter on my 360 - this is because I have a sh!tty 10/100 switch.

A couple of questions:

- Are the videos stored locally on the disk, or on a home SAN or other network drive? - maybe it's network traffic (a bad nic driver has caused this for me as well)
- Can you tell/hear if the hard drive(s) is thrashing like crazy? - might be highly fragmented.
- Have you tried streaming via windows media player? - could be a problem with tversity.
- Were you using k-lite codec pack? - If you install tversity without codecs, it will use whatever is already on the system for decoding (k-lite is pretty good in my experience), and those codecs could be bad/at fault.

I have worse hardware on one of my machines than you, so your specs aren't a problem (unless your equipment somehow became damaged):

- Athlon X2 4600+
- 2 gb RAM
- 8800 GTS
- files stored on a network machine running 2x250 gb raid 0 (that machine is identicaly except it's a 4200+ and has the raid) with tversity + k-lite codecs

Comment: - Everything is stored locally.
- The drive has 0 percent fragmentation (it's brand new).
- Tversity works fine, it is just Windows Media Center (on the PC) that is failing.
- Everything was working perfectly (before I reinstalled and after), until I did something which broke WMC.  I just can't figure out what I did.

Comment: @Kris Erickson - Are you able to check Process Explorer or Task Manager to see if anything is really chugging along while you're playing the videos?

Comment: Nope, the PC is border.  Using about 10% cpu...

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the hard drive as that is the only new component.   make sure all your connections are correct and that your sata cable isn't damaged.

next you may want to check the power settings for the hard drive.  the simple solution is turn off power management for the drive so it is on all the time.  I have heard of some hard drive having problems with windows 7 power settings at launch so update all your drivers using windows update.

that should solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

it maybe that windows media center is doing full drm stuff, which might explain why vlc works. have you hit windows update yet.  Also what power settings are you running?